# How to group data being split and posted to two backend Apache servers behind a frontend Nginx load balancer?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, load-balancing

For a requirement of my client, I want to set up a load balancer using Nginx with two upstream backend Apache webservers.

I think it should be like:

```
Server1: Nginx Load Balancer.
Server2: Apache Web Server.
Server3: Apache Web Server.
```

As Nginx distribute connection request to either server2 or server using round-robin method by default, it means, I have to put the same copy of website data on both server2 and server3 ?.

If that is the case, if more HTTP POSTs happens to server2 than server3, technically server2 gets more updates to the website database, right? so how does that sync data with server3?. I am a bit confused when it comes to the backend website data. I can do the server-side configuration easily but want to clear my confusion with the data being placed on server2 and server3.

Your advice would really be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure you are expressing correctly what you want to do. If you want to round-robin, both backends should serve the same content. Other factors may be involved for different traffic (I know nothing of nginx), but do you have a sticky session configured? that may make more requests in one server than another. As for backend website data, ask yourself what you want them to do not the other way around, that would be what they require from you.

Comment: ok what I meant, suppose if the website is a cart, even if the website copy is the same on server2 and server 3, the one which gets more POST gets more updates to their cart database right? and sometimes, if the same visitor checks his cart for the second or nth time and the request connection goes to the second backend server, he may not see that thing in his cart right?.

Comment: A cart? As in shopping cart? This has nothing to do with http servers.

Comment: Why not? You can host a shopping cart CMS website behind load balancers. I figured a solution to my question. Front end(Nginx load balancer) -> Backend -> Apache1 server and Apache2 server, both keeping same copy of website files, then both these Apache servers have a common Database server which has the DB of this e-commerce website where all the postings get saved. Why not load balancer and backend HTTP servers are not possible with this?.

Comment: No, I meant that you are probably refering to sessions and data in db behind the http servers, dynamic data, which is handled in these kind of scenarios, the amount of backend servers is irrelevant.

Comment: ok, you have a point there now with sessions, otherwise, I was answering your previous reply "This has nothing to do with http servers".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did a few research on this and found a solution to my particular requirement.

Front end:
Nginx load balancer

Back end:
Two apache web servers

Apache1: Install httpd, PHP, configure vhost and put all necessary files of the website.

Apache2: Install httpd, PHP, configure vhost and put the same files of the website you copied in Apache1 server.

Now, you need to set up a Database server that keeps the common database server for both Apache1 and Apache2.

I have now tested this setup by hosting a WordPress website and it works fine.

Comment: This might technically fulfill the requirements. However, now you have only single database, which often is a bottleneck. Therefore you might need to consider database replication and DB load balancing too.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good point. I will consider it definitely :)